# Rewind and fast forward YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube, video-playback, safari-extensions

How is it possible to rewind and fast forward YouTube video on both Android app and desktop? Is there any setting available on Android and any Safari extension available for desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the desktop <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> & <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> keys retard/advance the position of the "playhead" in the timeline by five seconds and <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> keys by ten seconds (<kbd>K</kbd> is play/pause). You can also press the numbers to jump around in the timeline (0 is the beginning, 2 is ~20%, 8 is ~80% etc.)

In the YouTube app., tapping the left or right side of the video will retard/advance by ten seconds:

[image]

[image]

If you are using a browser on your mobile device to view YouTube content, the screen tapping method is not an option, but "scrubbing" options are available. Press the timeline indicator, hold your finger down and drag downwards to select "Hi-speed", "Half-speed", "Quarter-speed" and "Fine" scrubbing, then swipe left or right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can fast-forward or rewind in 10 second increments by double tapping the video on the left or right edge.

http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-fast-forward-rewind-a-youtube-video-by-ten-seconds/

In a browser you can press the left or right arrow key to jump forward or back by 5 seconds. If you hold control and press an arrow key it will jump 10 seconds. Or if you hit a number, lets say 6. Then the video will jump 60% in to that point.

http://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip216.htm